# How to combine characters to create custom pattern in GROK

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm new to logstash and grok and have a question regarding a pattern.

> Jul 26 09:46:37

The above content contains `%{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}` and white spaces.

I need to know how to combine all these and create a pattern `%{sample_timestamp}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotes from the [Grok Custom Patterns Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) (RTFM):

> First, you can use the Oniguruma syntax for named capture which will
>   let you match a piece of text and save it as a field:
>
> ```
> (?<field_name>the pattern here)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Alternately, you can create a custom patterns file.
>
> - Create a directory called patterns with a file in it called extra (the file name doesn’t matter, but name it meaningfully for yourself)
> - In that file, write the pattern you need as the pattern name, a space, then the regexp for that pattern.

So you could create a pattern file that contained the line:

```
CUST_DATE %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}
```

> Then use the patterns_dir setting in this plugin to tell logstash
>   where your custom patterns directory is.

```
 filter {
   grok {
     patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
     match => { "message" => "%{CUST_DATE:datestamp}" }
   }
 }
```

Would result in the field:

```
 datestamp => "Jul 26 09:46:37"
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to add `/s` for the white spaces for the pattern 
`CUST_DATE %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}` ?

Answer (score 6):

### Filter

use **pattern_definitions** to define your patterns

```
filter {
  grok {
    pattern_definitions => { "MY_DATE" => "%{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}" }
    match => { "message" => "%{MY_DATE:timestamp}" }
  }
}
```

### Result

```
{
  "timestamp": "Jul 26 09:46:37"
}
```

Tested using Logstash 6.5